# Regex to check for repeating characters inside a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string for username and it can contain a (period) `.` (underscore) `_`. But I don't want the string to have more than 1 repeating `.` or `_`. So for example:

`alpha.beta.gamma` and `alpha.beta_gamma` are **acceptable**.

`alpha..beta`, `alpha__beta` and `alpha._beta` etc. are **not acceptable**.

Here is the regex that I am using `".*([._])\\1{1,}.*"`

It works for same characters, so it returns `true` for `alpha..beta` and `alpha__beta`. However, the regex returns `false` for `alpha._beta`.

How can I modify the regex to make it work for both `.` and `_` repeating match?

Comment: `if (s.matches(".*[._]{2}.*")) { return false; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this : `.*([._]){2,}.*`

[see Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SHowiy/1)

Answer (score 2):

The following should do the trick, by ensuring that the username does NOT match an undesired format:

```
// should not match this
/.*[._]{2,}.*/
```

This will ensure no more than one of either `_` or `.` can appear consecutively.

You may also want to consider being more specific than `.*`, potentially something like `[A-Za-z0-9]*`.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that in RegEx, groups and `*`/`+` operators can be arbitrarily nested.

This here matches all strings that start with some characters, and then are followed by arbitrarily many blocks, where each block starts with a '.' or a '_' and ends with arbitrarily many characters.

"[a-zA-Z]+([._][a-zA-Z]+)*"

Example (uses Scala, but that's irrelevant, it's the same String literals, and the same java.util.regex library):

```
for (example <- List(
  "aa.bb_c", "aa_.bb", "abc..cb", "a.b.c_d",
  "uidh.dh_thh.ths", "_a", "a_", "a_b_c",
  "tdh_ins_utu", "ghs.tah..hua",
  "kqkz..wkmqjk", ".wkqj", "..wkqm")
) println(
  ("'" + example + "' : ").padTo(20, ' ') + 
  example.matches("[a-zA-Z]+([._][a-zA-Z]+)*")
)
```

Output:

```
'aa.bb_c' :         true
'aa_.bb' :          false
'abc..cb' :         false
'a.b.c_d' :         true
'uidh.dh_thh.ths' : true
'_a' :              false
'a_' :              false
'a_b_c' :           true
'tdh_ins_utu' :     true
'ghs.tah..hua' :    false
'kqkz..wkmqjk' :    false
'.wkqj' :           false
'..wkqm' :          false
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, non-regex way, is just a simple method to check `if(s.contains...)` and your 4 options (`..`,`__`,`._`,`_.`);

```
return !(s.contains("..") || s.contains("__") || s.contains("._") || s.contains("_."));
```